# Yii Criteria: condition for relation

Tags: yii, compare, conditional-statements, criteria, relation

i have two tables: User and User_works (User HAS_MANY User_works).

How can I add a condition to be displayed only users with certain works

User contains fields: id | name | Other information

User_works: id | user_id | work_id

User Model:

```
public function relations()
{       
  return array(
    'works'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserWorks',
    '',
    'on' => 'works.user_id=t.id',
    'together'=>false,
    ),
  )
}
```

Controller:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('works');
$criteria->compare = ????
```

Comment: you want data from users with certain works mean you want to search from work_id from User_works table ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

I wanted something like that:

```
SQL "Select user.id from User, User_works Where User_works.user_id=User.id AND User_works.work_id=$SOMEVALUE"
```

User Model:

```
public function relations()
{       
  return array(
    'works'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserWorks',
    '',
    'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN', 
    'on' => 'works.user_id=t.id',
    'together'=>true,
    ),
  )
}
```

Controller:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('works'=>array('on' => 'works.user_id=t.id AND (works.work_id=$SOMEVALUE OR ...)'));
```

As a result, I get the users with the necessary works.

But а new problem arose. The number of pages in the Listview not correctly displays. 
List view does not consider the condition of necessary works. As a result, a number of page is wrong.

Solution :

```
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,      
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>1,
        ),
    ));
 $dataProvider->setTotalItemCount(count(User::Model()($criteria)));
```

or

Instead of setting the dataprovider criteria:

```
$dataProvider->criteria = $criteria
```

I set dataprovider->model criteria:

```
$dataProvider->model->setDbCriteria($criteria)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('works');
$criteria->compare('works.theField_name' , $someThing);
```

Comment: You have to set `$criteria->together = true`.

Comment: Can i do it without option "together = true"?

Comment: I think you don't need `together`, when you have `with`, it's done

Comment: where do you want to use this criteria?

Comment: @Taram you should try out both. I've had a scenario where my filters weren't working as expected because `together` was not set to `true`. Read the [Yii Relation guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) for a better explanation.

Comment: As a result i want: Two tables ("together=false" help me in this). The first table: Users with their personal information. And the second table: Users_id with work_id, where users_id can be repeated many times, because the user can have many works.

Comment: @tinybyte:  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Promouter', array(
   'criteria'=>$criteria));

Comment: what seems to be the problem? that dataprovider will make an array of Promouter objects, do you have problem showing it?

Comment: i want that as a result were only users with certain work_id. I can not create this condition

Comment: I think you have to define the join type of that relation to `inner join`, because by default it's `left join`.